# How can I display progress through a multi-step wise process to be carried out by user? (Smartphones / Tablets)

Tags: interaction-design, android, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you indicate progress to users in a multi-step form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/how-do-you-indicate-progress-to-users-in-a-multi-step-form)

What is the best way to display progress in a multi-step process (for e.g. linear filling various forms) on smartphones & tablets?

For more clarification: Its a business process where user needs to carry out few steps for its successful completion, using his/her touch devices.

Comment: There's no difference between mobiles & other devices when it comes to patterns of displaying progress through a task. Thus, the solutions to the question "[How do you indicate progress to users in a multi-step form?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/how-do-you-indicate-progress-to-users-in-a-multi-step-form)" are still applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would show them just below the title of the view as circles.

Just like this one: http://dribbble.com/shots/299804-Loan-Ranger

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I think you should try wireframeing the whole process for the given Smartphone / Tablet.

Here are some [free web and mobile ui wireframe kits](http://www.2expertsdesign.com/resources/40-free-web-and-mobile-ui-wireframe-kits-and-resources)

[Sqetch](http://www.eleqtriq.com/2010/08/sqetch-wireframe-toolkit/), an Illustrator Wireframe Toolkit

Comment: I'm sorry I guess my question is little misleading, I meant how can I show such a process (like normally in desktop apps we have next and previous button)